# How to build non-linear throttling for authentication APIs in Django rest framework ?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, throttling

DRF offers in-built throttling system where we can define rate limit. But how can we make it more secure by exponentially increasing the time limit of an API? Ie, if you make more than 10 calls/min to login API next min should allow only 5 API calls and so on. Time between subsequent API calls should increase exponentially until it hits a predefined threshold after which user should be blocked permanently.